# Tooltip variations with jquery version

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery UI tooltip widget, with version 1.10.4 of jQuery UI. I've noticed that code which works with jQuery 1.11.1 doesn't work with jQuery 3.1.0.

The code is supposed to replace all instances of title elements with a jQuery UI tooltip:

- [This fiddle uses 1.11.1](https://jsfiddle.net/ccwood/8LeLwzw7/); note that the three tooltips appear using jQuery UI

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).tooltip();
});
```

```css
 .ui-tooltip {
   padding: 8px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 9999;
   max-width: 300px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa;
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa;
   border-width: 2px;
   background-color: DarkSeaGreen;
   color: white;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p><a href="#" title="That&apos;s what this widget is">Tooltips</a> can be attached to any element. When you hover the element with your mouse, the title attribute is displayed in a little box next to the element, just like a native tooltip.</p>
<p>But as it's not a native tooltip, it can be styled. Any themes built with
  <a href="http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/" title="ThemeRoller: jQuery UI&apos;s theme builder application">ThemeRoller</a> will also style tooltips accordingly.</p>
<p>Tooltips are also useful for form elements, to show some additional information in the context of each field.</p>
<p>
  <label for="age">Your age:</label>
  <input id="age" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes.">
</p>
<p>Hover the field to see the tooltip.</p>
```

- [This fiddle uses 3.1.0](https://jsfiddle.net/ccwood/pykz81hn/); note that the three tooltips appear without jQuery UI styling

These fiddles use the code on the [default example of the tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/), which uses jQuery 1.12.4. I've had a look through the change logs of jQuery and haven't found anything which would suggest that the code which uses v3 shouldn't work - what have I missed?

Comment: Did you read the changelog of version 3.1.0?

Comment: You have not added the CSS, so there would be no styling

Comment: See here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/c06cLbdv/

Comment: @Hackerman - yes, although I accept I might have missed something. Is there something in particular you want to point out?

Comment: @Twisty both the code snippet and the jsfiddle examples include CSS - I'm not sure where you're suggesting I've omitted the CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works properly with latest version of jQuery UI: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/c06cLbdv/3/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
  .ui-tooltip {
    padding: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    max-width: 300px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa;
    border-width: 2px;
    background-color: DarkSeaGreen;
    color: white;
  }
  label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5em;
  }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
  $(document).tooltip();
});
</script>
```

I uncounted the following error running the older version with 3.1.0:

```
TypeError: elem.getClientRects is not a function
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js
Line 9816
```

But it does seem to work overall.

Comment: Thanks for realising that the latest version of jquery-ui fixes it. I wonder what changes were made...

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $('[title]').tooltip();
});
```